# NHibernate Query with joins and group by

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria-api

I have 4 assoiciated classes and need to do a query.

The classes are:

```
 public class Project{

     IList<Process> Processes{get;set;}

 }


 public class Process{

     IList<Association> Associations{get;set;}

 }


 public class Association{

     public IList<MonthCapacity> MonthCapacities{get;set;}
     public FieldOfActivity FieldOfActivity{get;set;}

 }

 public class MonthCapacity{

     public int Hours{get;set;}
     public DateTime MonthDate{get;set;}

 }

 public class FieldOfActivity{

 }
```

The query should result in a DTO:

```
 public class ChartDto{

      public Project Project{get;set;}
      public FieldOfActivity FieldOfActivity{get;set;}
      public int Hours{get;set;}

 }
```

I tried it with QueryOver but didn't get it to work. Could someone help me out?

Thanks in advance Tobi

Comment: this would result in a 5 x join if all is loaded at once. this could be very slow.

Comment: performance does not matter unless it doesn't take 10 minutes *g*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you test this:

```
Process processAlias = null;
Association assocAlias = null;
FieldOfActivity actAlias = null;

var subquery = QueryOver.Of<MonthCapacity>()
    .Where(m => m.Association == assocAlias)
    .Select(Projections.Sum<MonthCapacity>(m => m.Hours));

var results = session.QueryOver<Project>()
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Processes, () => processAlias)
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Associations, () => assocAlias)
    .JoinAlias(p => p.FieldOfActivity, () => actAlias)
    .Select(p => new ChartDto { Project = p, FieldOfActivity = actAlias, Hours = Projections.Subquery(subquery) })
    .List();
```

Edit:

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Project>()
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Processes, () => processAlias)
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Associations, () => assocAlias)
    .JoinAlias(p => p.FieldOfActivity, () => actAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(p => new ChartDto { Project = p, FieldOfActivity = actAlias, Hours = 0 })
        .Select(Projections.Subquery(subquery))
    )
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(objects =>
    {
        var chart = (ChartDto)objects[0];
        chart.Hours = (int)objects[1];
        return chart;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Just 2 problems: 
- return is no IList<ChartDto>
- hours must be as sum ;-)

Comment: Update: Got this part working. Last problem: Projections.Subquery is not datatype int but projection

Comment: now it is compilable but throws the following Exception:  Could not determine member from new HoursOfFieldOfActivityInProjectDvo() {Project = p, FieldOfActivity = value(Com.QueoMedia.RessourcentoolEGFS.Persistence.Impl.ProjectDao+<>c__DisplayClass6+<>c__DisplayClass9).actAlias, Hours = 0}